# Java application deploying on Linux platform

Tags: java, linux, tomcat8.5

I am trying to deploy project war file on Linux platform and its giving me following error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:1207f4ed-32d0-44e8-ae1c-308b157e9903

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
```

Server details

```
Server - Tomcat v8.5
```

configuration in the property file.

```
    jdbc.url = jdbc:sqlserver://DC01ODSDBDV03;databaseName=ExecDB_Stg;integratedSecurity=true;

   hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
   hibernate.show_sql = true
   hibernate.format_sql = true
```

We have tried adding the following javakerberos property but it didnt work.

```
  authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To save you a lot of pain really try to convince sql admins to allow you the password authentication.

Otherwise you need to run Tomcat under an AD service account, which is not difficult if you kow how to do that.

I wrote a blog about [SPNEGO authentication](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/apache-tomcat-spnego-authentication-configuration/).  you do not need all the steps, it is enough that Tomcat will run  as AD service. (until configuring krb5.ini file)

Comment: could you pls tell what is AD service account? sorry for the basic question.

Comment: @MSV please read my blog or search the net. it is an AD user (e. g. tomcat) which has spn (service provider name) assigned, effectively binding the service to 'run as an AD user' on specific host and protocol